# nginx nodejs uri segment not found

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

My uri work greats on localhost. But on production, doesn't seem so.
[image]

The two picture, one is taken from localhost, other is taken from production server.

[image]

And my nginx default file is like this

```
. . .
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got two `server{}` block in default file. The first block allow to receive all traffic of all domain path. So deleting that one and save the file will solve the problem.